# Flutter Send a post request while waiting for gps data

Tags: flutter, http-post

I'm stuck on my flutter project, I want to send the gps coordinate every time the user open the app to check if its position is on specific place referenced on my base (if yes it send a notification). I have two futures, one of which is dependent on the other (sending needs gps data).

```
  import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
  import 'package:location/location.dart';
  import 'dart:convert';

  class Islandmenu extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ......
 }

  Future<void>getgpscoordinates() async{
    final locdata = await Location().getLocation();
    List<double> gps= [locdata.latitude,locdata.longitude];
    return gps;
   }

  Future<void>checkUser(gps) async{
    const String userurl="*********/input_dbco.php";
    final response = await http.post(userurl, body:jsonEncode({
      "id": "",
      "gps":[gps[0],gps[1]],
      "dateco": "",
    }));
    return response;
  }
}//end of class
```

but it's make my VM crash so i guess i do it in the wrong way ^^.

Comment: how are you using these futures ? consider adding minimum code

Comment: i've edited my post

Comment: where are you calling your futures ?

Comment: nowhere special, i'd like to auto execute but yes it is probably the problem.